Why does running a gzip command in combination with sponge in my Nextflow script produce an empty file?
I have a fairly simple nextflow process - it takes a file, does some simple processing, and uses sponge to write to the same file. At the end of the script, it uses gzip to compress the file. However, the file produced is empty. If I don't use the gzip command at the end of the script, the uncompressed file is produced as expected.
However, if I change the sponge command to write to a named file instead of using sponge, gzip works as expected. Why does this happen, and is there any way I can still use sponge and also gzip my end file?
My original code, which produces an empty .txt.gz file:
process processFILE {
    container = params.docker_container
    publishDir "${params.output}", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path file
    path output

    output:
    path "${file.baseName}.txt.gz"

    script:
    def output_file = "${file.baseName}.txt"

    """
    # Add header line to file
    sed -i '1i column1\\tcolumn2\\tcolumn3' ${output_file}

    # Add lineX to the header if the parameter is not null
    if [ -n "${params.criteria_1}" ]; then
        echo '# LineX' \
        | cat - ${output_file} \
        | sponge ${output_file}
    fi

    # Add lineZ to the header if the parameter is set to true
    if [ "${params.criteria_2}" = "true" ]; then
        echo '# LineZ' \
        | cat - ${output_file} \
        | sponge ${output_file}
    fi

    # Compress
    gzip ${output_file}
    """
}

However, when I change it to the following, it works:
process processFILE {
    container = params.docker_container
    publishDir "${params.output}", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path file
    path output

    output:
    path "${file.baseName}.txt.gz"

    script:
    def output_file = "${file.baseName}.txt"
    def final_output_file = "${file.baseName}.txt.gz"

    """
    # Add header line to file
    sed -i '1i column1\\tcolumn2\\tcolumn3' ${output_file}

    # Add lineX to the header if the parameter is not null
    if [ -n "${params.criteria_1}" ]; then
        echo '# LineX' \
        | cat - ${output_file} \
        | sponge ${output_file}
    fi

    # Add lineZ to the header if the parameter is set to true
    if [ "${params.criteria_2}" = "true" ]; then
        echo '# LineZ' \
        | cat - ${output_file} > test.txt
    fi

    # Compress
    gzip -c test.txt > ${final_output_file}
    """
}


Didn't you already ask this question? If it was closed, edit the closed instance rather than asking a new copy.

(I asked, on that existing instance, that you build a [MRE] that doesn't require nextflow for people to see the problem or test their answers; I see that's still outstanding).

Hint for minimizing the question to the essential part: By the time gzip runs, sponge should have been already terminated. Leave out all the commands before that and just test with a static file. ¶ Since you said your .gz file was empty (as in filesize = 0 bytes) but even an empty file has 26 bytes when compressed with gzip, it is likely that the issue only comes from gzip file vs. gzip -c file > outfile and maybe some nextflow-specific stuff.

Because it was my first question on Stack Overflow, it is posted to the Staging Ground for 24 hours (which is where you answered it) before it is automatically posted on the main site (which is here). This is an automatic process for all first time posters on Stack Overflow.

Thank you for the comments and suggestions - in the end I changed it to a suggestion that Charles Duffy provided when it was posted within the Staging Ground, which avoids the use of sponge. I will reply with that answer and close the question.

If you are running sed -i on the file anyway, you can easily refactor these additions into the same script to avoid rewriting the same data up to three times. Your code will run faster and your SSD disk won't wear out quite as fast.

As suggested by @charles-duffy on the staging ground post, I have removed the use of sponge which solved the issue.
cat <(printf 'column1\tcolumn2\tcolumn3\n'; [ -n "${params.criteria_1}" ] && echo "# LineX"; [ -n "${params.criteria_2}" ] && echo "# LineZ") "${output_file}" | gzip >"${final_output_file}"

